# Flipping bits and crossing strings induction problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Consider a binary string consisting of n bits, where n ≥ 1. We are allowed to perform
the following operation: we can replace a 1 by a x, and when we do that we must flip the
two bits immediately adjacent to it that remain. Thus 1100 becomes 0x10 when we replace
the 1 in the middle by a x, and then we get 0xx1 when we replace the new 1. Prove that we
can convert a binary string of length n into a string of n x’s (we refer to this as “crossing
out” a string) using the above operation if and only if the string has an odd number of 1s.

What would be the best way to start on this? I'm mainly  trying to find an induction step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first move has been made, the string is effectively cut into two pieces (one of which may be empty), to the left and right of the first x, and there will be no further interaction between these. So by the IH, we will be successful if both pieces have an odd number of $1$'s. This shows, first of all, that we will succeed if the original string had an odd number of $1$'s, by making the first move on the leftmost $1$.

The converse follows in the same style, by discussing separately the various configurations $010$, $011$, $111$ the first move might be applied to.

Comment: What do you mean by  the converse statement?

Comment: @bobby: The opposite implication. Christian proved that if the string has an odd number of $1$s, then it can be converted to $x$s; the converse is the statement that if it can be converted to $x$s, then it has an odd number of $1$s.

Comment: What does Christian Remling mean by discussing separately the various configurations 010, 011,111

Comment: Say your first move is $\ldots 010 \ldots \to L1x1R$, and this can be converted to $x$'s only. Then by the IH, $L$ and $R$ both have an odd number of $1$'s. It now follows that the original string $L010R$ had an odd number of $1$'s. Discuss the other cases in the same style.